# Python Selenium, the text of the next element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I can get the text of the first element. But I do not know how to go through the entire list and get the text of each element. Here is the tree from the site:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VReXl.jpg)

So I get the text of the first element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@my-peer-link='participant.user_id']").click()
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@ng-bind=\"'@' + user.username\"]").text)
```

In each

> div class="md_modal_list_peer_wrap clearfix" ng-repeat="participant in
>   chatFull.participants.participants"

is contained

> div class="md_modal_list_peer_name"

which contains

> a class="md_modal_list_peer_name"
>   my-peer-link="participant.user_id">Олег

which you need to press. That is, execute:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@my-peer-link='participant.user_id']").click()
```

After that, a new window opens, from which I get the text of the element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@ng-bind=\"'@' + user.username\"]").text
```

But there are several of these elements and I need to get the text with everyone:

> div class="md_modal_list_peer_wrap clearfix" ng-repeat="participant in
>   chatFull.participants.participants"

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vladimir, I haven't done a careful analysis of this problem; however, could it be as simple as this?

Rather than using

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@ng-bind=\"'@' + user.username\"]").text
```

could you use:

```
for span in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@ng-bind=\"'@' + user.username\"]"):
    span.text
```

(Notice plural in `find_elements_by_xpath'.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to click each element and store the text in a list:

So first use

```
elements_to_click = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@my-peer-link='participant.user_id']"
```

This will return a list of elements

Loop through those elements by

- clicking on element
- switch to the new window (When a new WindowHandle was created, otherwise skip this step.)
- get the text via 
  `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@ng-bind=\"'@' + user.username\"]").text`
- store it in a list
- close window (When a new WindowHandle is created, otherwise skip this step.)
- switch to previous window